# How can I filter by nested data in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, nestjs

I have a User entity that has a role prop:

```
@Prop({ type: Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Roles' })
  role: Role | Types.ObjectId;
```

Role type:

```
export interface Role {
  _id: Types.ObjectId;
  name: string;
  permissions: Permission[] | Types.ObjectId[];
}
```

Query to get users:

```
async getUsers(body: EntitiesGetDto): Promise<User[]> {
    return this.usersModel
      .find(body.filter)
      .skip(body.offset)
      .limit(body.limit)
      .populate('role')
      .sort(body.sort ?? {});
  }
```

How can I get users filtered by role? (by role._id or role.name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using 2 different Models and schemas try using [aggregate lookup](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate-lookup), instead of using populate.
Replace the query fields to match your use case:

```
// initiate the aggregate func
const aggr = this.userModel.aggregate();
// filter by user fields
aggr.match(body.filter);
// add lookup to match with the roles schema
aggr.append(
    [{ $lookup: {
        from: "role",
        localField: "user_role",
        foreignField: "user_role",
        as: "roles"
      }
    },
    // match the requested fields 
    { $match: { '$roles.name': "..some name.." } },
    // return the relevant data from the Model
    { $project: {
        _id: 1,
        role_name: '$roles.name',
        user_field3: 1,
        user_field4: 1,
      }
    }
  ]);
```